# Resizing the middle part of the page while keeping its children constrained

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a page with a footer and a header. I want both of them to stay fixed height when resizing. The middle bit should resize on resize to fill in the rest of the space.

The problem starts when the middle div has too much content. Then it goes past the footer (see the fiddle). I'd prefer it to stay constrained in the middle bit and instead have it obeying the `overflow-y: scroll`. (see [fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wRPMpe) for the explanation.

I know I could recalculate the height on resize with JS, but was wondering if there is something I could do with pure CSS. Not a master on css, perhaps I could use CSS variables in some clever way?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not very sure I understand your question. Maybe `footer{position: fixed;}` is what you need.

Comment: `fixed` almost works, but it makes content hide behind the footer and the header. I supposed I could add fixed padding to the middle bit since it's known and fixed, wonder if there is a nicer solution.